# onClick call JSP page and render results

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have links on my page that that have an onClick event. The links look something like:

```
<a class='person' href='http://{urlPath}?id="+x[i].getAttribute('id')+"'"+"onClick='personClick()</a>
```

You can see that I tack on the user ID as a URL parameter from some xml that I previously returned.

Because I'm using Colorbox to open a new page when the link is clicked, onClick looks like:

```
function personClick(){
        $(".person").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
}
```

My issue is this: when the link is clicked, I need to call another jsp that queries the database using the URL parameter "id" and renders the XML that is returned. I'm not exactly sure how to do this. Trying to render the HTML in the same jsp that the database query is made isn't working too well. I also thought about calling the jsp that queries within a javascript function, then using the javascript DOM parser to parse and render the data, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that either.

I'm not sure if I made my problem clear or not. If not, let me know and I'll explain further.